# AWS Lambda Error - "errorType": "string", "errorMessage": "handled"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, error-handling, aws-lambda

I am trying to write my first lambda function and use my MySQL database. The credentials to the database are correct and both are in the same subnet. The purpose of the function is to show all tables. Here my Node.js 10.x script:

```
'use strict';
console.log("Loading controls function");

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const mysql = require('mysql');

exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    // context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false; 
    
    const connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.RDS_HOST,
        user: process.env.RDS_USER,
        password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
    });
    
    connection.query('select * from controls;', function (error, results, fields) {
      if (error){
        context.fail();  
        return { statusCode: 500, body: JSON.stringify(error) }
      } 
      else{
        context.succeed('Success');  
        return { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(results) }
      } 
    });
};
```

The error looks like this:

{
"errorType": "string",
"errorMessage": "handled",
"trace": []
}

Does anyone could imagine what could be the issue?

Comment: What do the Cloudwatch logs say?

Comment: Since I've put a bounty on this, it is worth noting that my encounter with this issue occurs when returning a Javascript `async/await` function (with or without a `try/catch` block) in a Lambda serving as a step in an AWS Step Function. I cannot get meaningful error data passed to the following step, as I only get the generic object OP reports.

Comment: Add logging statements to your code and then look for them in the CloudWatch logs. Also consider that the Lambda function may be exceeding the timeout defined - although there's usually an explicit error message in CloudWatch for that.

Comment: I do already have logging statement in my code that I can see in the CloudWatch logs. But I need the error in the next step to feed in order to feed into some additional business logic. The lambda is definitely not timing out.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK a lambda handler should either be an `async` function or accept a `callback`. Given your code it is simpler to make it accept a `callback`.

```
'use strict';
console.log("Loading controls function");

const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const mysql = require('mysql');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.RDS_HOST,
    user: process.env.RDS_USER,
    password: process.env.RDS_PASSWORD,
    database: process.env.RDS_DATABASE
  });
    
  connection.query('select * from controls;', function (error, results, fields) {
    if(error) {
      context.fail();
      return callback(null, { statusCode: 500, body: JSON.stringify(error) });
    } 

    context.succeed('Success');  
    callback(null, { statusCode: 200, body: JSON.stringify(results) });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a while guess that you have not configured the VPC settings for your Lambda function. You see, by default, Lambda doesn't actually get an IP as far as your concerned, or a security group. So it cannot communicate to anything in your VPC by default really.

Go to the Lambda, go to the VPC settings, and make sure you configure the Lambda to run in Subnets in your VPC, and give it a security group which will enable it to access your database.